# SSH cannot connect from the internet/no ping from router

Tags: networking, debian, routing, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to open ssh of my server to the Internet so that I can do remote management, but it's not working.

Drilling down the problem, I found out that I cannot also ping my server  from the router management console (a TP-LINK TL-R470T+ model).

Router management console:

[image]

Router Virtual Server Configuration:

[image]

My Debian Version:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.9.0-8-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27)
```

IPTables configuration:

```
$ sudo /sbin/iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Network configuration:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.80  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::d294:66ff:feae:33b5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d0:94:66:ae:33:b5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 41030  bytes 8177279 (7.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 58  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 54962  bytes 72415932 (69.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 165132  bytes 35628022 (33.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 165132  bytes 35628022 (33.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

SSHD Configuration:

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.


Port 22
Port 3051
AllowTcpForwarding Yes

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

No ideas of what's wrong. How can I solve this issue and allow my server to be pinged from the router and accessed from the Internet ?

Comment: Can  you ping your router from the server?

Comment: Yes, but not the way back.

Comment: Can you add another host on the Network and see if it can ping the server?

Comment: I have some other nodes in the network, and all of them can ping the server. In other words, the LAN nodes can ping the server. I cannot ping the server only from the router or them WAN.

Comment: And the other nodes can ping the router, and router can ping the other nodes?

Comment: @AbuZaid, yes. All nodes can ping the router, router can ping all nodes except the server, server can ping all nodes and router.

Comment: The information you have provided does not show why the Router will not be able to ping the server. I would do basic troubleshooting, check arp cache, do packet capture and so on for layer 2 or layer 3 issues.

Comment: @AbuZaid Please suggest what information must be added...

Comment: What I meant was there is nothing wrong in the configuration you have provided for the Router or server. And the pings should work.

Comment: That's why I'm posting here.... It should work, but it is not working and I need help to find out why...

Comment: Correct, so next steps would be to look at layer 2 and layer 3. Do packet captures, check arp and so on.